# Append row with condition

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to append rows from a "child" workbook into an Excel "masterfile", only if the rows contain "nonconformity" in the 4th cells.

The idea is presented here:
[image]

The workbook child is **wkUP** and the master is **wkDW**.

My loop is appending wrong rows. I guess my issue is in the `i` and the length of the table.

```vb
    Dim i, iLastRow As Integer
    Dim oLastRow As ListRow
    Dim srcRow As Range
    iLastRow = wkUP.Sheets("DATA").ListObjects("TAB1").ListRows.Count
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
        If wkUP.Sheets("DATA").Cells(i, 4).Value = "nonconformity" Then
            Set srcRow = wkUP.Sheets("DATA").ListObjects("TAB1").ListRows(i).Range
            Set oLastRow = wkDW.Worksheets("NC").ListObjects("tbl_NC").ListRows.Add
            srcRow.Copy
            oLastRow.Range.Cells(9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `i` in two different contexts:

- In relation to the sheet: `.Cells(i, 4)`
- In relation to the table: `.ListRows(i)`

You need to be consistent; here is one approach that uses `i` only in reference to the table.

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = wkUP.Sheets("DATA").ListObjects("TAB1")

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
lastRow = tbl.ListRows.Count

For i = 1 To lastRow
    If tbl.ListColumns("Answer").DataBodyRange.Cells(i).Value = "nonconformity" Then
        Set srcRow = tbl.ListRows(i).Range
        ...
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Oh right ! I need to change wkUP.Sheets("DATA").Cells(i, 4).Value to have the i working in inside the table and not in the whole sheet.

Comment: Another option is to use `AutoFilter`, instead of looping row-by-row.